# How do I access the DataContext in from another window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

**Issues**

1. When I open the `SecondView` and type something in the `TextBox` and
   then I close the `Window` and re-open it, there is no text there as
   if it didn't get bound. I believe this is due to the fact that I am
   creating a new instance of the `View` everytime I click the button
   that displays the `SecondView`
2. I don't know how to access the properties inside the
   `SecondViewModel` from my `MainViewModel` without having to create a
   new instance.

I want to be able to get the `Name` property from the `SecondViewModel` inside the `GrabDataFromSecondViewModelCommand`

Starting off with the `MainView`, this is what it looks like.

```
...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding ShowSecondViewCommand}"
                Height="25" Width="100"/>

        <Button Command="{Binding GrabDataFromSecondViewDataContext}"
                Height="25" Width="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

and it's `DataContext looks like this.`

```
class MainViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand ShowSecondViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand GrabDataFromSecondViewModelCommand { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ShowSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                var SecondView = new SecondView();
                SecondView.ShowDialog();
            }, o => true);


            GrabDataFromSecondViewModelCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                /*Not sure how to grab the data from SecondViewModel
                 without having to initialize a new instance of it.
                 */

            }, o => true);
        }
    }
```

And the `SecondView` looks like this.

```
...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SecondView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:SecondViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"
                 Height="25" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
```

and it's `DataContext` like so.

```
class SecondViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public SecondViewModel()
        {

        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

and I might as well throw the `RelayCommand` & `ObservableObject` in here

**ObservableObject**

class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

}

**RelayCommand**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<object, bool> canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

**Update**
So I changed the SHowCommand to do this

```
ShowSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
                var SecondView = new SecondView(SecondViewModel);
                SecondView.ShowDialog();
            }, o => true);
```

and then inside the `SecondView` windows initializer list I set the DataContext like so

```
public SecondView(SecondViewModel svm)
        {
            DataContext = svm;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Which uses a new instance everytime the command opens the window.

**new update**
Now I got it like so

```
 public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; } = new SecondViewModel();

        public MainViewModel()
        {

            ShowSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                var SecondView = new SecondView(SecondViewModel);
                SecondView.ShowDialog();
            }, o => true);
```

and it still compiles, but it still creates a new instance.

Comment: Do not assign a view model in the XAML of SecondWindow. Instead, pass one after creating a SecondWindow instance, ideally one that is a property of MainViewModel, e.g. `var secondView = new SecondView { DataContext = this.SecondViewModel };`

Comment: So I would create a new instance of the `SecondViewModel` inside the `MainViewModel` and then pass that new instance to the `SecondView` window constructor? And inside the COnstructor of that `Window` I'm setting the DataContext in the code behind?

Comment: That's not a constructor, but an initializer list. Anyway, you pass the value of a MainViewModel property to the DataContext of a SecondView instance. At what time you initialize that property, I can't tell.

Comment: Because if I do that, it still won't save what I typed into the textbox because there is a new empty ViewModel passed everytime I open that window.

Comment: A "new empty ViewModel"? Why are you doing that? Why not initialize some SecondViewModel  property *once* and reuse it?

Comment: That's what I want to do but I think I'm looking at this in a different way than you, I'll update the code so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Why `SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();` in the Execute method? That makes no sense. Make it a property and initialize it **once**, outside of the command Execute action.

Comment: Because otherwise it's just passing through a null object right? Since the `SettingsViewModel` is a property that hasnt been initialized, or am I wrong?

Comment: "a property that hasnt been initialized" -> solution: initialize it before the command is invoked, e.g. in the MainViewModel constructor, or by an initializer at its declaration.

Comment: Sharing stuff across Forms in Windows Forms was annoying, so that was one thing they fixed in WPF. If you want anything to be shared in WPF, you just put it into the App.xaml. Every window has everything in it's own XAML File, and the App Xaml one.

Comment: The `MainViewModel` gets initialized everytime the `SecondView` closes though, so where ever I set it to be a new instance it's going to do it everytime the MainView is initialized and that happens everytime the SecondView is closed

Comment: @Christopher That's totally wrong when there already is a MainViewModel.

Comment: Declare the property like this: `public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; } = new SecondViewModel();`

Comment: Okay so the `MainViewModel` is not a ViewModel for everything, it's just the ViewModel for the first window, might of been a bad naming convention on my part, no?

Comment: @Clemens That's exactly what I did, but `new SecondViewModel` because you can't initialize it without using `new`

Comment: If you did exactly that, `SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();` inside the Execute method would not compile. So no, this is not exactly what you did. Note that I added the `new` operator in my comment.

Comment: I'll update the post real quick

Comment: I think I got it working by setting the DataContext in the instance of the ViewModel rather than the initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

Use composition and let your `MainViewModel` have a reference to the `SecondViewModel`. This way you can directly access it from within the scope of `MainViewModel`. When creating a new instance of `SecondView` (shouldn't be the responsibility of the view model) just assign the reference of the `SecondViewModel` to the views `DataContext` and remove the parameterized constructor from `SecondView`.

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public SecondViewModel SecondViewModel { get; }
    public RelayCommand ShowSecondViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand GrabDataFromSecondViewModelCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.SecondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
        ShowSecondViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            var SecondView = new SecondView() { DataContext = this.SecondViewModel };
            SecondView.ShowDialog();
        }, o => true);


        GrabDataFromSecondViewModelCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            // Directly access the view model
            string valueFromAssociatedViewModel = this.SecondViewModel.Name;
        }, o => true);
    }
}
```

I think your last update should work.